# cal-heatmap - How to change text color based on rect .q1{} color?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, calendar, heatmap

Given this single day from a 1-month (30-day) calendar of day/price values using cal-heatmap:

```
<g>
<rect class="q1 graph-rect hover_cursor" width="34" height="34" x="144" y="36">
<title>12345</title>
<text class="subdomain-text" x="161" y="53" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central"> 8</text>
</g>
```

I know the  object is styled using a class name (`.q1`).

But, how can we style the  element separately from the generic `.subdomain-text{}` CSS rule that hits ALL  elements?

If the .q1 class was attached to the parent element `<g>`, we could use a descendant CSS selector to handle this, so essentially

1) I want to be able to do this:

```
`g.q1 text {fill:red}`
```

...which will let me have custom text colors based on the fact this overall date is in the .ql css color range.

2) I also want to uniquely style the text for days before "today"...

3) ...and separately style the default style used for NULL prices which I believe comes from `.subdomain-text {}` CSS rule. (not all 30 days will necessarily have a price value - it could be null).

*Is there a way to style the  element beyond the default `.subdomain-text{}` rule?*

Comment: It sounds like you would want to set those styles in the code that generates the SVG.

Comment: Can you put up a jsfiddle highlighting the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write new CSS rules for the text element, for example:

```
.cal-heatmap-container{
  .q1  + title + .subdomain-text {
    fill: red;
  }
  .q2,
  .q3,
  .q4,
  .q5{
    + title + .subdomain-text {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }
  }
}
```

More info: https://github.com/kamisama/cal-heatmap/issues/143

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to edit CSS rules like that:

```
.cal-heatmap-container .subdomain-text {
    font-size: 16px;
    fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Aug 2020

I know the question is old, but if any of you still looking to color the 'text' and its 'background' cell color, then here's the answer.

#### Text color

Use `fill` on a `.subdomain-text` class. You cannot use <strike>`color: white`</strike> property.

```
.subdomain-text {
    fill: white;
}
```

#### Background cell color

Use the same `fill` on a `.graph-rect` class

```
.graph-rect {
    fill: dodgerblue;
}
```

If you have multiple `svg` elements in your file then use the `svg.cal-heatmap-container` to add your css to be more precise.

```
svg.cal-heatmap-container .subdomain-text {
    fill: white;
}
```